# MEF isn't loading my plugin

Tags: c#, plugins, reflection, mef

I've implemented a very small plugin system in `C# with MEF`. But my plugins won't be loaded. In the `Aggregate-Catalog` I can see `my plugin listed`. But, after I'll compose these parts, there isn't my plugin in the plugin list, what I'm doing wrong?

Here's a snippet of my code:

Plugin-Loader:

```
    [ImportMany(typeof(IFetchService))]
    private IFetchService[] _pluginList;
    private AggregateCatalog _pluginCatalog;
    private const string pluginPathKey = "PluginPath";
    ...

    public PluginManager(ApplicationContext context)
    {
        var dirCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[pluginPathKey]);
        //Here's my plugin listed...
        _pluginCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(dirCatalog);

        var compositionContainer = new CompositionContainer(_pluginCatalog);
        compositionContainer.ComposeParts(this);
     }
     ...
```

And here, the plugin itself:

```
[Export(typeof(IFetchService))]
public class MySamplePlugin : IFetchService
{
    public MySamplePlugin()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Plugin entered");
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Has someone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this wrong. The `ImportMany` attribute of the `_pluginList` field doesn't make any sense, since the the plugin manager instance will be created by you, not by the DI container.

You have to create another class that will import all your plugins.

```
[Export]
class SomeClass
{
    readonly IFetchService[] pluginList;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public SomeClass([ImportMany(typeof(IFetchService))]IFetchService[] pluginList)
    {
        this.pluginList = pluginList;
    }
}
```

Now, you can let the DI container compose an instance of this `SomeClass` for you. You will see that its `pluginList` field contains your plugin reference.